# How to create test run in Rally using the REST webservice and Soapui

Tags: soapui, rally

Is it possible to create a test run / result in rally using soap UI. My idea record the result after running a test set?

Are there any existing public soap ui projects that do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to create Test Case Results in Rally using Rally's SOAP interface (and therefore by using SOAPUI).

However, Rally's SOAP API has been deprecated. Webservices 2.0 is REST-only. The last version of WSAPI that supported SOAP is 1.43 - which will be permanently deprecated 1 year from it's release date of 20-Jun-2013 (approx. 1 year from now).

If you're getting started developing your integration, I'd highly recommend using REST. More information on Rally's REST toolkits is available here:

- [Rally REST Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET)
- [Rally REST Toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava)
- [Rally Ruby REST Toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby)

Comment: SOAP UI also supports using a REST interface